# .net core 5.0 angular 10 running on windows IIS server

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

the page comes up blank but this error keep the page from loading. If anyone found a sure way to fix. . Thanks!

`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. /main-es2015.381030b3d21caf13619a.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. /polyfills-es2015.8005eab2c6721bac0373.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. scripts.dfe5da540b50ddf65e43.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you host angular or react base app inside IIS. you need to add rewrite rule like below.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

First install [url rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

When you add this, it will server your JS files.

Comment: Yes I try that but for .net core does not seem to work correctly. Thanks for the quick reply.  I still get the same error.

Comment: this line needs to change accordingly to your settings.
<action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.html" />